# H2 Database simulate Oracle XMLtype - Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, h2

I have the following column in one of my hibernate entities:

```
    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @ColumnTransformer(read = "to_clob(xmlContent)", write = "?")
    @Column(name="XMLCONTENT", updatable = false, columnDefinition = "XMLType")
    private String xmlContent;
```

However when I have `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create` on hibernate it fails to create the particular table giving me the following error:

`Unknown data type: "XMLTYPE"; SQL statement:`

So basically I can't include this table/entity at all in tests with the H2 database. I need to have an XE at least installed.

Is there any workaround/solution to this, possibly another in memory database supports this?

Comment: Store XML as a clob?